# Angular 2 error:

Tags: angular

Playing around with Angular 2 and trying to get this simple code working.
yet I keep getting an error of:

> EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for Tab(undefined). Make sure
>   they all have valid type or annotations.

As far ng2 is not injecting in c`onstructor(tabs:Tabs) {…` into the constructor

Here is the entire code:

```
///<reference path="../../typings/zone.js/zone.js.d.ts"/>

import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'tab',
    template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)">
        {{tab.tabTitle}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
})
export class Tab {
    @Input() tabTitle: string;
    public active:boolean;
    constructor(tabs:Tabs) {
        this.active = false;
        tabs.addTab(this);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'tabs',
    directives: [Tab],
    template: `
    <tab tabTitle="Tab 1">
        Here's some content.
    </tab>
  `,
})

export class Tabs {
    tabs: Tab[] = [];
    selectTab(tab: Tab) {
        this.tabs.forEach((myTab) => {
            myTab.active = false;
        });
        tab.active = true;
    }

    addTab(tab: Tab) {
        if (this.tabs.length === 0) {
            tab.active = true;
        }
        this.tabs.push(tab);
    }
}
```

tx

Sean

Answer (score 5):

That's because your `Tabs` class is defined after your `Tab` class and [classes in javascript aren't hoisted](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html).

So you have to use [`forwardRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/forwardRef-function.html) to reference a not yet defined class.

```js
export class Tab {
    @Input() tabTitle: string;
    public active:boolean;
    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => Tabs)) tabs:Tabs) {
        this.active = false;
        tabs.addTab(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or declare the classes in two modules/namespaces. This allows you to hold a reference to the object that will contain the actual classes and by the time Angular comes around to dereference the classes, they would be already created.

Comment: thank you!!!! didnt think about ordering, so used to functions and std hoistings in es3

Answer (score -1):

You have two solutions:
Inject your Tabs class globally at bootstrap:

```
bootstrap(MainCmp, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Tabs]);
```

On inject Tabs locally with a binding property,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tab',
    bindings: [Tabs],   // injected here
    template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)">
    [...]
```