# Class is not injectable if it is defined right after a component with meta annotation

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6, angular

I just started off with Angular2 quick start project. Have a simple application working. I added `DataService` class, so that the code will have separation of concern.

Initially I've added the `DataService` class write after the my main component of app which is `MyAppComponent` like below.

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
    'selector': 'my-app',
    template: `<div *ngFor="#item of items">{{item}}</div>`,
    directives: [NgFor],
    providers: [DataService] //taking service as injectable
})
export class MyAppComponent {
    items: Array<number>;
    constructor(service: DataService) {
        this.items = service.getItems(); //retrieving list to bind on the UI.
    }
}
//created service, but its after the component which has meta annotation
export class DataService {
    items: Array<number>;
    constructor() {
        this.items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    }
    getItems() {
        return this.items; //return the items list
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent)
```

Above code compiles correctly, but at run-time it throws below error.

> EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for
>   MyAppComponent(undefined). Make sure they all have valid type or
>   annotations.

After 2 hours playing with the code, I shifted the `DataService` just above the `MyAppComponent` which got worked. I'm really glad that issue solved.

But I'm very curious to know that, why it wasn't working if I placed `DataService` class right after the `class` with `MetaAnnotation` over it?

**Edit**

I tried solution give by @Günter Zöchbauer like below,

```
import {Component, View, Inject, forwardRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
    'selector': 'my-app',
    template: `<div *ngFor="#item of items">{{item}}</div>`,
    directives: [NgFor],
    providers: [DataService] //tried commenting this still throws error.
})
export class MyAppComponent {
    items: Array<number>;
    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => DataService)) service: DataService) {
        this.items = service.getItems();
    }
}
```

but still getting error in console. which looks wiered

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't hoist classes. Either use [forwardRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/forwardRef-function.html), move `DataService` to it's own file or move `DataService` class above `MyAppComponent`

```
@Component({
    'selector': 'my-app',
    template: `<div *ngFor="#item of items">{{item}}</div>`,
    directives: [NgFor],
    providers: [forwardRef(() => DataService)] //taking service as injectable
})
export class MyAppComponent {
    items: Array<number>;
    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => DataService)) service: DataService) {
        this.items = service.getItems(); //retrieving list to bind on the UI.
    }
}
```

See also
- [Angular 2 error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306041/angular-2-error/34309922#34309922)
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html

Comment: @Gunter in this case the forwardRef must go in the providers property

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this edit has solved my problem..but may I know why we need to do that twice?

Comment: I assume because on both places you're referring a class that is not yet known because both lines are before the class declaration.