# How to properly use dependency injections in Angular2?

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I have had mixed success with resolving issues with DI. I have read a few tutorials and I get the jist but after making some nested DIs with my custom services things have started to fall apart.

Could someone explain when to use useFactory instead of useClass? I have seen the ng2 docs and I have seen the examples but I cannot map them to my problems. Currently my bootstrapper looks like this:

```js
bootstrap(
    App,
    [
        FORM_PROVIDERS,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: PathLocationStrategy }),
        provide(RequestOptions, { useClass: DefaultRequestOptions }),
        provide(MsgService, { useClass: MsgService }),
        provide(HttpAdvanced, { useFactory: (MsgService, HTTP_PROVIDERS) => new HttpAdvanced(MsgService, HTTP_PROVIDERS), deps: [MsgService, HTTP_PROVIDERS] }),
        provide(AuthService, { useFactory: (HttpAdvanced) => new AuthService(HttpAdvanced), deps: [HttpAdvanced, HTTP_PROVIDERS, MsgService] }),
        provide(FormBuilderAdvanced, { useFactory: (FormBuilder, HttpAdvanced) => new FormBuilderAdvanced(FormBuilder, HttpAdvanced), deps: [FormBuilder, HttpAdvanced] }),
        provide(MsgServiceInternal, { useClass: MsgServiceInternal })
    ]
);
```

And my latest issue is:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of AuthService! (HeaderBar -> AuthService).
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.http.get is not a function
```

My dependencies work like

```
HttpAdvanced        -> Http(ng2), MsgService
MsgService          -> MsgServiceInternal
AuthService         -> HttpAdvanced
FormBuilderAdvanced -> FormBuilder(ng2), HttpAdvanced
```

***1.*** Am I properly using provide / useClass / useFactory and how do I provide services that have other dependencies?

Also, I have at one place in my code:

```js
static isUserInjector() {
    return (next, prev) => Injector.resolveAndCreate([AuthService, provide(HttpAdvanced, { useClass: HttpAdvanced })]).get(AuthService).isUser();
}
```

Because I want to have a function that I provide to

```js
@CanActivate(AuthService.isEditorInjector())
```

but I can't use constructor injection because @CanActivate is outside of the class scope so I can't inject the service inside the controller and then reference like `@CanActivate(this.authService.isEditor())`

***2.*** What would be a good solution for this?

SOME CODE:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'ShowStats',
    templateUrl: './dest/views/showStats/showStats.html',
    directives: [ COMMON_DIRECTIVES, UsersCount, AdminsList, GlobalWishlist, PopularTrack ]
})
export class ShowStats {
    authService : AuthService;

    constructor( authService : AuthService ){
        this.authService = authService;
    }
}

... next file ...

@Injectable()
export class HttpAdvanced {
    msgService: MsgService;
    http: Http;

    constructor(msgService: MsgService, http: Http) {
        this.msgService = msgService;
        this.http = http;
    }

    /*
     * This is for plain ol' GET requests .. with callback of course.
     */
    public get(url, callback) {
        return this.http.get(url).subscribe((res) => {
            let data = res.json().data;
            callback(data);
        }, this.msgService.httpErrorHandler);
    }
.... other code for HttpAdvanced
```

***3.*** 
Does the order of importing files matter for DI? I think i noticed that since I have MsgService and MsgServiceInternal in the same file and MsgService depends on Internal that I had to put Internal before but I'm not 100% Is it the same  of order of `importing` ?

***4.***
So if I simply do:

```js
bootstrap(
    App,
    [
        FORM_PROVIDERS,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: PathLocationStrategy }),
        provide(RequestOptions, { useClass: DefaultRequestOptions }),
        MsgService,
        HttpAdvanced,
        AuthService,
        FormBuilderAdvanced,
        MsgServiceInternal
    ]
);
```

I get:

```
Cannot resolve all parameters for 'FormBuilderAdvanced'(?, ?). 
Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have 
valid type annotations and that 'FormBuilderAdvanced' is decorated 
with Injectable.
```

I used to remove this error with the `useFactory` but I'm confused now. Does this mean the deps aren't injected because it can't see them or what?

The Form class:

```js
export class FormBuilderAdvanced {
    http: HttpAdvanced;
    fb: FormBuilder;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder, http: HttpAdvanced) {
        this.fb = fb;
        this.http = http;
    }

    create(controlNames: string[], submissionUrl: string, getter?: any) {
        return new Form(this.fb, this.http, controlNames, submissionUrl, getter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you missed the `HeaderBar` dependency when defining the `AuthService` provider?

Comment: To **4**. When you want DI inject a class that has constructor parameters you need to add the `Injectable` annotation: `@Injectable() export class FormBuilderAdvanced {`. In your case there is another problem.  DI can't resolve `controlNames: string[], submissionUrl: string, getter?: any`. There are no providers for `string[]` or `any`. What do you  want to get passed to the constructor here? Maybe this is a case for `useValue` or `useFactory`.

Comment: Aw man I put it everywhere but here. Can't believe it was this stupid

Comment: DI is quite confusing when you start using it. I had this 2 years ago when they introduced it in Angular.dart. We have covered the better part in this question I guess. One part not mentioned here is hierarchy. When to add providers to `bootstrap()` and when to a `@Component()` / `@Directive()` annotation. If you want to elaborate this as well check out for example the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34804459#34804459 or create a new one question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You question doesn't provide enough information to know for sure but this is probably enough

```ts
bootstrap(
    App,
    [
        FORM_PROVIDERS,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: PathLocationStrategy }),
        provide(RequestOptions, { useClass: DefaultRequestOptions }),
        // provide(MsgService, { useClass: MsgService }),
        MsgService, // is just fine when no special behavior is required
        // provide(HttpAdvanced, { useFactory: (MsgService, HTTP_PROVIDERS) => new HttpAdvanced(MsgService, HTTP_PROVIDERS), deps: [MsgService, HTTP_PROVIDERS] }),
        provide(Http, {useClass: HttpAdvanced});
        AuthService,
        provide(FormBuilder, { useClass: FormBuilderAdvanced}),
        MsgServiceInternal)
    ]
);
```

If you want to make a class available for injection, just add the type to the providers list (`provide(AuthService)` and just `AuthService` do the same).
If you want inject a different class than the one requested, use `useClass`.

Example

```ts
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }
}
```

If your providers contain

```ts
provide(Http, {useClass: HttpAdvanced});
```

then `MyService` (which has a dependency on `Http`) gets injected `HttpAdvanced` instead.
Ensure you have this line after `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to override the default `Http` provider, contained in `HTTP_PROVIDERS`.

If DI can't resolve dependencies by itself because they aren't just other providers, then use `useFactory`.

As mentioned above,

> Ensure you have this line after `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to override the default `Http` provider, contained in `HTTP_PROVIDERS`.

the order in the list of providers does matter.
When the providers list contains multiple providers for a type then only the last one is used.

The order of the **imports** doesn't matter.

The order of dependent classes within one file **does** matter because classes are not hoisted.

Example

```ts
export class ClassA {
   // constructor(private b: ClassB) {} // ClassB is unknown here
   constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => DataService)) {
   }
}

export class ClassB {
}
```

If the code of `ClassB` is above `ClassA`, `forwardRef()` isn't necessary.

See also [Class is not injectable if it is defined right after a component with meta annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838804/class-is-not-injectable-if-it-is-defined-right-after-a-component-with-meta-annot)

Comment: I apologise for not enough info, I did not wan't to pollute with redundant  code. The thing is that I'm not providing HttpAdvanced instead of usual Http, it's that I'm providing Http to HttpAdvanced like class HttpAdvanced { constructor(http: Http) { this.http = http; } } and I'm also providing HttpAdvnced to other components but not as Http but by itself. I'll add some code

Comment: No problem, I understand that this is an iterative process. In this case just replace `provide(Http, {useClass: HttpAdvanced});` by `HttpAdvanced`.

Comment: When do I write `provide(HttpAdvanced, { useClass: HttpAdvanced })` and when do I just write `HttpAdvanced` like with MsgService in your example

Comment: They do both the same. `provide(X, { useClass: Y})` is only necessary if `X` and `Y` are not the same type and when you want a class requesting `X` get `Y` instead. This is for example for testing. Your service requests `Http` but for tests you do `provide(Http, { useClass: MockHttp })` then your service gets `MockHttp` instead of the requested `Http`?

Comment: Added 4th question :/

Answer (score 4):

To complete a bit the Günter's great and clear answer, I would say that I would use `useFactory` to instantiate by myself classes associated with providers in the following use cases:

- When you want to select the element to inject into the contructor of the element associated with the provider. For example, if you want to extend the `HTTP` class and provide explicitly a specific concrete class for parameters (here `XHRBackend` instead of `ConnectionBackend`). Here is a sample:

  ```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    })
  ]);
  ```

@Langley provides interesting hints in this question: [Handling 401s globally with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934009/handling-401s-globally-with-angular-2).

- Another cool usage of the `useFactory` is to instantiate a class from a third-party library into the context of Angular2 (Zones)

  ```
  bootstrap(App, [
    provide(Mousetrap, { useFactory: () => new Mousetrap() })
  ]);
  ```

@alexpods provides this very elegant solution in this question: [View is not updated on change in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592857/view-is-not-updated-on-change-in-angular2).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry