# Injecting services into services in angular2

Tags: angular

I want to write some kind of Broadcast mechanism to dynamically create and use `EventEmitter`s in my user context. To do so I inject the an `EmitterService`

```
@Injectable()
export class BroadcastService implements OnInit {
    private _emitters: { [channel: string]: EventEmitter<any> } = {};    
    constructor() {}    
    get(channel: string): EventEmitter<any> {
        if (!this._emitters[channel]) { 
            this._emitters[channel] = new EventEmitter();
        }
        return this._emitters[channel];
    }    
    ngOnInit() { }    
}
```

My components structure looks like this:

```
                [root]
                 |  |
           [comp-a][comp-b]
```

In my `root` component I inject the `BroadcastService` to make sure every sub-component uses the same Broadcast Channels. In addition other services like an `AuthService` are injected (in the `root` too, that's basically my user context)

```
@Component({
    provider: [BroadcastService, AuthService]
})
```

The `AuthService` (and others) are using the `BroadcastService` for emit events:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService extends BaseService {      
constructor(
        http: Http,
        @Inject(BroadcastService) private emitterService: BroadcastService)
    {              
        super(http);                 
    }
    ...
    // Example usage of Broadcast
    login(username: string, password: string) {
        // do the login, when successfully:
        this.emitterService.get("online").emit(true);
    }
}
```

The error I get:
`EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'AuthService'(Http, undefined @Inject(undefined)). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'AuthService' is decorated with Injectable.`

What I tried:

1. Putting another root component on top the the current root component to inject the `BroadcastService` there, same result
2. Adding/Removing the @Inject to the constructor parameter, no changes
3. Begging and crying, didn't help

The strangest part is, that this works with one of my other services and doesn't with the rest of them (well, I didn't try all, but those I tried didn't work). Do you have any clues what the problem could be? Or is this maybe just a bug (I'm using angular2 in 2.0.0-beta.2)

Comment: Did you add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [...])`? `@Inject(BroadcastService)` is redundant AFAIK.

Comment: yes. and I really have no idea, what the problem could be anymore

Comment: I guess it's the order of the classes in the source file. Are `AuthService` and `BroadcastService` in the same file? Change the order of these two classes or use `forwardRef`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a `forwardRef` is required

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService extends BaseService {      
constructor(
        http: Http,
        @Inject(forwardRef(()  => BroadcastService)) private emitterService: BroadcastService)
    {              
        super(http);                 
    }
    ...
    // Example usage of Broadcast
    login(username: string, password: string) {
        // do the login, when successfully:
        this.emitterService.get("online").emit(true);
    }
}
```

could also (or instead of) be necessary in

```
@Component({
    provider: [BroadcastService, AuthService]
})
```

depending on how you code is organized. 
This is not necessary when each class is defined in its own file.

See also [Angular 2 error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306041/angular-2-error)

Comment: Great, thanks. Do you have a nice guide to understand **what exactly** is going on. I know what a forward reference in general is and why it is needed. But this special case is still a bit of a misteria for me

Comment: Classes are not hoisted and therefore not yet known where they are used as type. With `forwardRef` the resolution of the type is delayed to later when the whole file content is known. See also http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/forwardRef-function.html